# Сериализация данных из формы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть форма, данные из которой я получаю с помощью serialize, дальше их отправляю на php скрипт, в котором хочу вывести весь полученный массив и отдельные свойства из него. Но почему-то массив не выводится подскажите почему? 
js файл

```
    var data = $("form").serialize();
    data = decodeURI(data);
    $.post("result.php",data,function(data,status){ 
         console.log(data);
    }
```

php файл

```
echo $_POST["data"];//вывожу массив
echo $_POST["цена"];
```

Comment: массивы надо выводить либо с помощью `print_r($_POST['data'])`. Либо `var_dump`. Но у вас как я понимаю не выводит ничего?

Comment: `data = decodeURI(data);` - зачем это действие у вас в коде? Покажите код самой формы. Чтобы исправить ошибку самостоятельно, выполните: `var_dump($_POST);` и посмотрите на результат. `echo` не распечатывает массивы. Для этого есть функция `print_r`.

Comment: В массиве null. Использую data = decodeURI(data), потому что в input name русские символы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data=$_POST["data"];//ваш массив с данными 
parse_str($data, $formData);//преобразует ваши сеарилизованные данные в массив
echo"<pre>";
print_r($formData);//распечатываем массив
 echo"</pre>";
например ваша сеарилизация FirstName=Mickey&LastName=Mouse,обратимся к FirstName 
echo $formData["FirstName"];//выведет Mickey
```

Comment: что бы ваш скрипт заработал, нужно заменить data на {data} в js скрипте